# Coefficients of geodesic equations

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

The geodesic equations is the system of equations which often takes the form

$\frac{d}{dt}(Eu^{'}+Fv^{'})=\frac{1}{2}(E_{u}(u^{'})^{2}+F_{u}u^{'}v^{'} +G_{u}(v^{'})^{2})$

$\frac{d}{dt}(Fu^{'}+Gv^{'})=\frac{1}{2}(E_{v}(u^{'})^{2}+F_{v}u^{'}v^{'} +G_{v}(v^{'})^{2})$

It is not clear from the context whether these have variable coefficients or constant.

Comment: Did you understand how $(E,F,G)$ are defined? Did you work out for any parametrized surface?

Comment: @Narasimham yes and yes. The equations hold given a surface and an arbitrary parametrisation giving us E,F and G

Comment: Since the equations contain partial derivatives $E_u$ etc, these functions are not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the coefficients are not constant. Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310109/find-range-of-parameters-for-which-a-given-curve-is-a-geodesic)  question for an example.